# Display number of rows containing a range of numbers (between 0-9) in R

Tags: r, filter, rows

I am trying to count the number of rows in my dataset (called data) that contain a range of numbers (e.g. between 0 and 9) by using R. I have not created a dataframe and my dataset is directly imported from a csv file into R.

EXAMPLE OF DATASET (INPUT)

| MESSAGE |
| --- |
| I have to wait 3 days |
| Feel quite tired |
| No way is 7pm already |
| It is too late now |
| This is beautiful |

So the output would be 2 rows (row 1 and 2)

I have tried the following code but it provides me the wrong output number of posts (3) - so I know I am definitely doing something wrong.

```
    data = read.csv (xxxxxx)
    #count number of rows that contain numbers between 0 and 9 
    numbers= filter(data, !grepl("[0-9]",MESSAGE))
    length(numbers)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filter` function returns a dataframe back and counting `length` on a dataframe returns number of columns and not rows. Also you are using regex to select rows which do not have a number by introducing `!` in front.

You can use `sum`. + `grepl` :

```
result <- sum(grepl('[0-9]', data$MESSAGE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the code like below if there are at least one digit

```
> length(grep("\\d", MESSAGE, value = TRUE))
[1] 2
```

---

If you want to find out the rows where there is a single digit, you can try

```
> length(grep("\\b\\d(?![0-9])", MESSAGE, value = TRUE, perl = TRUE))
[1] 2
```

**Data**

```
MESSAGE <- c(
  "I have to wait 3 days",
  "Feel quite tired",
  "No way is 7pm already",
  "It is too late now",
  "This is beautiful"
)
```